# QuickFix acceptance test

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

May someone please explain what exactly acceptance test for QuickFix have to do(test for)? 
Right now i have done several test that test the latency and througput of messages but i have no idea what the acceptance test for QuickFix shoud test.
I have searched over the net for this but i didnt manage to find the answer of the question. So if someone know what i have to test for or have done such test please write it here so i and other like me can see it. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'acceptance test' I'm assuming you are referring to some kind of conformance test?  If so, then it depends on the business scenario that you are trying to test and how the FIX connection supports that.  For example, you FIX connection might be a pricing feed.  In which case conformance testing might cover:

1. Fix session level tests (i.e. checking both sides are conforming to the FIX protocol
2. Testing subscription to symbols and that prices are being received

However, if you FIX session was an order feed then tests would include order related scenarios e.g. testing that you can submit orders, receive order updates (fills, rejections and cancellations etc).  Testing the behaviour of orders if you get disconnected (ie. do your GTC orders get pulled if you lose connection from the exchange etc)

An STP conformance test would hopefully result in answers to questions like:

1. How do I guarantee that I have received all the deals
2. How can I replay deals that might have been done whilst I've been disconnected?
3. How do I uniquely identify a trade? (i.e which FIX tags or combination of tags do I need)

Whether you are conformance testing an STP, pricing or orders fix session, you will always want to do the basic fix session level tests.

Do this help?